# Table Widget Needed

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a requirement to build a table widget for sitecore 8 update 5. They should be able to choose the number of columns from 1 to 6 and then edit the content of the table in experience editor.

I know tables can be created using the rich text editor but they really want this widget.

Finally my question is being new to sitecore what would be the recommended approach in building this widget? Keeping in mind they want to be able to choose the number of columns between 1 to 6 and with as many rows as they want and edit in experience editor.

Comment: The rich text editor is really the only sensible choice here.  I realise you said they "really want a widget" but there's not a good alternative without an enormous amount of pointless work.

Have a look into creating snippets in the rich text editor - this allows your table to be pre-fabricated with CSS classes and formatting options to make it easier on the editors.

Comment: The alternative is perhaps to add row/cell items as children of your page item and have the 'widget' read those - you could create them using JS in page editor.

Comment: I completely agree @RichardHauer but after challenging the client they still wanted this widget. So my thoughts are to use angular on a sublayout to create a dynamic table so they can edit the columns and row as well as content and then use the output json as new item to store in DB and finally assign that item to sublayout datasource field. Do you this this will work? just thought best to run the idea past you guys. Cheers

Comment: sounds like it will work, if they feel like spending $10k to solve a $50 problem.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHauer in that case I will give it a go. I guess if they have the money I am more then happy to take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this in the past by using a hierarchy of child items.  The data source for your Table rendering may have a field for a header or styles and its children define the rows.  Rows have children to define cells.  You can use edit frames with insert, delete and move up/down buttons for both rows and cells.  If you need to limit columns to 6 or fewer, you may need to implement a custom button rather than use the standard insert button. The cells can then have whatever fields you need or dynamic placeholders.

Comment: Because there is a six column limit, you might as well put six fields in a row item. Easier, Faster. I made something similar, because it was so that every column had a different data type. Follow it then it is logical to put six columns in a row item.